# My laptop suddenly failed to boot. Can someone help me diagnose the problem?

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, gparted, bios

My laptop suddenly failed to boot. Can someone help me diagnose the problem? Below are some of the suggestions I have already tried (I'm not sure what they all mean).

I tried using the BIOS to change boot mode and specify a boot device, but these options were unavailable. Here is the info tab.

[image]

And this is the boot tab. No boot device list is present.

[image]

I also couldn't fix the issue by booting from Ubuntu live USB. GParted gives the error `Input/output error during read on /dev/sda` and gnome-disks showed this.

[image]

Finally I tried to use some command line tools to check disk status and these showed errors as well. This is the output of parted.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda 'print'
Error: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA PS3111 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 21.0MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

And this is the output from fsck (I tried the suggested commands in this output and they gave similar results).

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: There is no doubt that your harddisk somehow got corrupted, judging from the last error message and showing a size of 21 MB. I'd say you can rule out BIOS issues and focus on HD recovery. I hope someone can help with that.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I am reading somewhere about the possibility that the SSD has come unplugged. Might be a dumb quesiton  but is the disk showing 21mb definitely the main harddisk? This is on a standard laptop with just one SSD.

Comment: I would think so, since it shows `/dev/sda` (which should be the first disk). And looks like it has a Phison PS3111 controller.

Comment: It looks like there are several problems with SSD's using this controller: https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/90glkw/buyer_beware_sata_ssds_with_phison_s11_controllers/

Comment: @ArturMeinild thank you so much for finding that. This is indeed a budget laptop so it's most likely a cheap SSD and it has failed.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but at least I think the problem is diagnosed.

Comment: @ArturMeinild If you want to summarize these comments in an answer I will mark it as correct. Might help future people who google the controller name. Otherwise no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshots and terminal outputs, it looks like the SSD is the problem (showing only 21 MB and IO / superblock errors).

Further investigation shows that the SSD controller (Phison PS3111) [has caused trouble for a number of people](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/90glkw/buyer_beware_sata_ssds_with_phison_s11_controllers/) since its introduction. This controller is mostly used in budget SSD's.

Judging from this, it seems most likely your SSD has simply failed.